# Quasi-Coherence of $Hom$ Sheaf

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite presented $R$-module, so we have the sequence
$$  0 \to R^n \to R^m \to A \to 0  $$

therefore $R \to A$ gives rise for morphism of finite type $f:Spec(A) \to Spec(R)$ between affine schemes $Spec(A), Spec(R)$. By construction $\mathcal{O}_A = f_*(\mathcal{O}_R)$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_R $ algebra.

Now consider the dual sheaf $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)$. Obviously it's a $\mathcal{O}_{SpecR}$-module. By the locally canonical $\mathcal{O}_{A}$-action via $a' \times h \mapsto (a \mapsto h(aa'))$ the $\mathcal{O}_{SpecR}$-module $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)$ becomes an $\mathcal{O}_A$-module.

I want to see how to proof that $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)$ is a **quasi coherent** $\mathcal{O}_A$-module.

My idea is to show that $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)= \widetilde{Hom_A(A,R)}$ holds, using fact that on affine schemes the tilde functor provides via $M \to \widetilde{M}$ a 1-to-1 correspondence between $A$-modules and quasi coherent $\mathcal{O}_A$-modules.

I suppose that it would suffice to show that for every ideal $(p)$ the $A$-module $Hom_A(A,R)$ permutates with localisation by $(p)$, so that 
$$Hom_A(A,R)_{(p)} = Hom_{A_{(p)}}(A_{(p)},R_{(p)})$$

but I don't see any way how to prove it and especially how to use the information that $A$ has a finite presentation as $R$-module.

Other question: Does it suffice to show this to proof  $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)= \widetilde{Hom_A(A,R)}$ and equivalently the quasi coherence of $\underline{Hom}_{SpecR}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)$ ? The matter is how to interpret $R_{(p)}$ where $(p)$ is an ideal of $A$?

Comment: The localization formula of the homs which you have written (note: you should rather write $\mathfrak{p}$ in my opinion for an arbitrary prime ideal not necessarily a principal ideal $(p)$) is well-known and requires to be true exactly that $A$ is finitely presented. You find a proof of this localization formula of homs in Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry. It is Proposition 2.10 on page 69. It follows basically because localization is flat and since tensor product commutes with homs in case that $A$ is finitely presented.

Comment: Continued: I think this will suffice to solve your problem because, indeed, the hom sheaf is defined locally in terms of the constituent sheaves, here $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(R)}$.

Comment: @user213008:Oh sorry for confusing notation, meant by $(p)$ a arbitrary prime $\mathfrak{p}$, not only the principle. My problem is the following one:
By showing that $Hom_A(A,R)$ commutates with localisations by primes $p$ of $R$ I get that $\underline{Hom}_{SpecA}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R)$ is quasi coherent as $\mathcal{O}_R$-module, so it is the coker is the sequence $ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_R^I \to \mathcal{O}_R^J \to \underline{Hom}_{SpecA}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R) \to 0$ (or equivalently $ 0 \to R^I \to R^J \to Hom_A(A, R) \to 0$ as $R$-module).

Comment: But what I really want is that $\underline{Hom}_{SpecA}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R) $ is quasi coherent as $\mathcal{O}_A$-module, so that $ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_A^I \to \mathcal{O}_A^J \to \underline{Hom}_{SpecA}(\mathcal{O}_A, \mathcal{O}_R) \to 0$ (or equivalently $ 0 \to A^I \to A^J \to Hom_A(A, R) \to 0$ as $A$-module). $A$ is not flat, tensoring sequence $ 0 \to R^I \to R^J \to Hom_A(A, R) \to 0$ by $A$ isn't exact, so I need another argument ...

Comment: Have you an idea how can I reduce the claim to the proof that $ 0 \to R^I \to R^J \to Hom_A(A, R) \to 0$ is exact?

Comment: I understand your problem better now but have no solution at hand. Just one comment: If you write $\mathrm{Hom}_A(A,R)$, this usually means $A$-module homomorphisms from $A$ to $R$, but here $R$ has **no** structure as an $A$-module (at least I don't know which), just $A$ the trivial one as an $A$-module. What you are seeking for is something like ${}_A\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,R)$, i.e. you consider $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,R)$ ($R$-module homomorphisms from $A$ to $R$) as an $A$-module as you explained in the question. At least, this is how I understand the situation right now.

Comment: yes exactly, by $Hom_A(A,R)$ I meant your ${}_A\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,R)$ as $Hom_R(A,R)$ endowed with extra $A$-module structure by $a' \times h \mapsto (a \mapsto h(aa'))$